# Why the event.pageY in mousemove event could not be updated when mouse moves?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mousemove

I want to use the current `event.pageY` value when `mousemove` event is fired. But it seems that my `event.pageY` value doesn't update. Here is part of my code (it's already in the callback function of the `mousemove` event):

```
 var deltaX = self.mouse.startX - event.pageX,
     deltaY = self.mouse.startY - event.pageY;
 if (self.mouse.endTime - self.mouse.startTime < 300){                  
                // Drag down
                console.log(event.pageY); // 1
                if(Math.abs(deltaX) < Math.abs(deltaY) && deltaY < 0){
                    console.log(event.pageY);  // 2
             ....
```

The first `console.log(event.pageY)` will update automatically as mouse moves, but the second one doesn't update, it seems that it keeps the value calculated in `deltaY`. So how can I get the updated `event.pageY` value as mouse moves in the inner "if"?

Comment: Unless you omitted some code, I can't see why your console.log calls are spitting out different values. Are you sure you're not getting confused by the conditional execution sometimes emitting one value and sometimes emitting two?

Answer (score 1):

event.pageY doesn't get updated automatically, it is a property of the event object which is generated when the event is triggered so it is constant inside the event handler.

Comment: I said it's part of my code, which means it's already in the callback function of the mousemove event.That's why I said the first console.log(event.pageY) will update automatically and the second one doesn't.